# What does $\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}_X(n)$ represent geometrically?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For simplicity let's say $A$ is a noetherian ring, $S = A[x_0, \ldots, x_r]$, and $X = \operatorname{Proj} S = \mathbb{P}^r_A$.  I want to understand what, if anything, the sheaf $$\mathscr{F} := \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}_X(n)$$ means geometrically.

**First,** I think that if I put $$Y := \operatorname{Spec}(S) \setminus V(S_+) = \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_A \setminus V(S_+)$$ then I have a morphism $q : Y \to X$ (which takes prime ideals corresponding to closed points to their homogenizations) and that $\mathscr{F} = q_\ast \mathcal{O}_Y$.  Is this correct?  I'm not confident enough with these things yet to trust myself on something like that yet.  [**EDIT**: To be more specific, I'm having difficulty constructing the underlying function $q : Y \to X$ in a way that makes it tractable to show that $q$ is Zariski-continuous, to the point that I'm wondering whether such a map exists in general.]

**Second**, whether the above is correct or not, does $\mathscr{F}$ have a nice geometric meaning of some sort?

Comment: The answer is yes for the first question.

Comment: For an arbitrary noetherian ring $A$?  I had a bit of trouble checking that that actually gave a continuous map if it wasn't just over an algebraically closed field.  Do you have a source?

Comment: This holds for any commutative ring $A$. I will write a proof if you like.

Comment: Could you? I was having trouble defining the map $q$ in a way that made it easy to check that the map was even continuous...

Comment: Dear Daniel, it seems that I misundertood your real question. This is not really transparent in your original post. I will delete my answer and probably you should edit your question or post another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $q$ is well defined for any positive graded ring $S$.

For any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $S$, denote by $\mathfrak p^h$ the homogeneous ideal associated to $\mathfrak p$. It is also prime. For any homogeneous ideal $I$, by construction we have:

> $I\subseteq \mathfrak p^h $ if and only if $I\subseteq \mathfrak p$.

Taking $I=S_+$, we see that $q(\mathfrak p):=\mathfrak p^h\in \mathrm{Proj}(S)$ if $\mathfrak p\notin V(S_+)$. This shows that $q$ is actually a map
$$q: \mathrm{Spec}(S) \setminus V(S_+)\to \mathrm{Proj}(S).$$
Moreover the above equivalence shows that 
$$ q^{-1}(V_+(I))=V(I) \setminus V(S_+). $$
Hence $q$ is continuous. Finally, for any $f\in S_+$ homogeneous, we have 
$$q^{-1}(D_+(f))=D(f).$$ 
This helps to show the equality of sheaves you are after.

Comment: Can you expand on what's meant by $\mathfrak{p}^h$?  I took it to mean the ideal generated by the homogeneous parts of each element of $\mathfrak{p}$, but then it appears for instance that in $k[x, y]$ we have $(y-x^2)$ prime but $(y-x^2)^h = (x^2, y)$ not even radical.  Or am I making a mistake or working with the wrong definition?

Comment: Ah, I think I see -- I want to work with something *larger*, not smaller, so I should take the maximal homogeneous ideal contained inside of $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. Your second comment is correct: $\mathfrak p^h$ is the ideal generated by the homogeneous elements of $\mathfrak p$